# nsolid heap snapshot and cpu profiles not appearing in console

Tags: node.js, docker, nsolid

I'm new to N|Solid. I just got it running locally in my docker stack -- I can open the the console in my browser and it's successfully connecting to and reporting on my instances.

However, when I click "New Heap Snapshot" or "New CPU Profile" in the console I'm just met with a banner message that says e.g. "Working on CPU Profile: 0 of 1 complete". That message sits there indefinitely and the snapshot/profile never appears in the console.

In my docker logs when I trigger these via the console I see things like:

**Application log**

```
NSOLID 6693: starting cpu profile collection 30d39e20-60f6-448d-b3a0-9bf40382a9f3
NSOLID 6693: collecting profile data for reply
```

**nsolid console log**

```
{
  "time":"2020-03-24T22:54:57.792Z",
  "hostname":"83c226c1764d",
  "pid":8,
  "level":"info",
  "name":"nsolid-console:lib/http-server.js",
  "message":"Handling 3 connected queries."
}
```

I have no idea how to debug this, and all of my internet searches have yield zero results.

**Relevant parts of docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  nsolid:
    image: nodesource/nsolid-console
    container_name: nsolid
    environment:
      - NODE_DEBUG=nsolid
      - NSOLID_CONSOLE_LICENSE_KEY=MY_KEY
    ports:
      - "6753:6753"
      - "9001:9001"
      - "9002:9002"
      - "9003:9003"
  server:
    container_name: rumpus
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: local.dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - nsolid
    volumes:
      - ./server/app/:/var/www/app/
    environment:
      - NODE_DEBUG=nsolid
      - NSOLID_APPNAME=rumpus
      - NSOLID_COMMAND=nsolid:9001
      - NSOLID_DATA=nsolid:9002
      - NSOLID_BULK=nsolid:9003
    ports:
      # HTTP
      - "8080:8080"
      # DEBUGGING
      - "9229:9229"
      - "9230:9230"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you please add the tag latest to your image so it should be 'nodesource/nsolid-console:latest'

That should pull 3.10.1 which should work as expected

Comment: After updating I got a timeout the first attempt at the heap snapshot, but everything seems to be in order now. Thanks!